# json - can name contain number with alphabets or alphabets with number because ng-controller is not displaying

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
$scope.fundOverview = [{
                                "Rank": 1,
                                "Fund": "7IM AAP Adventurous C Acc",
                                "Group": "7IM Investment Funds|CFIM",
                                "Focus": "Equity",
                                "Yield": 1.5,
                                "1Y": 21.051114,
                                "3Y": 31.467272,
                                "5Y": 55.113164,
                                "Del_function": "Y"
                           }];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

From [Style Guide Google:](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml)

> JSON maps can use any Unicode character in key names.
>   The property name naming rules do not apply when a JSON object is used as a map. A map (also referred to as an associative array) is a data type with arbitrary key/value pairs that use the keys to access the corresponding values. JSON objects and JSON maps look the same at runtime; this distinction is relevant to the design of the API. The API documentation should indicate when JSON objects are used as maps.
>
> The keys of a map do not have to obey the naming guidelines for property names. Map keys may contain any Unicode characters. Clients can access these properties using the square bracket notation familiar for maps (for example, result.thumbnails["72"]).

Comment: I need a solution you have given the explanation I want to I am able to display all the values in the index page but if i call the "1Y": 21.051114,
                                "3Y": 31.467272,
                                "5Y": 55.113164, its not working if I just oneyear means it is working please help me

Comment: @john  you show a json ... I need more code to be able to find the error. Can you edit your code?

Comment: Here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/nataraj30/b1ngmrc6/2/ this js fiddle is not working  and the working fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/nataraj30/0p16n1vd/1/ I want the first fiddle to work like second fiddle please help